# Rails 6 session variables not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relatively new Rails 6 app (Rails 6.1.3.1), so there's not a whole lot of customization yet. However, I cannot get session variables to persist.

For example, if I put something like the following in a controller action:

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def home
    byebug
    session[:foo] = 'bar'
  end
end
```

I would expect `session[:foo]` to be `nil` on the first request, but I would expect it to be set to `'bar'` on all subsequent requests. However, it's `nil` every time.

This is causing a major problem with CSRF functionality, because the `session[:_csrf_token]` is being reset on every request. This means that no request has a valid CSRF token, so I can't get login to work.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going on. I've tried monkeying around with browser settings and environment settings, but nothing has worked.

I've been banging my head on this for a couple days now. What am I missing? What might cause the session to be reset on every request?

Here is some more context:

```rb
# Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.1'

gem 'rails', '6.1.3.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise'
gem 'image_processing'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'roadie-rails'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'tailwindcss-rails'
gem 'view_component', require: 'view_component/engine'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'web-console'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'minitest-focus'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'pdf-inspector'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rexml'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :development, :production do
  gem 'stripe'
end
```

```rb
# application.rb

require_relative "boot"

require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

class Env
  def self.var(*args)
    var = args.join('_').upcase
    ENV[var] || Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym].dig(*args)
  end
end

module Foobar
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.1

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")

    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/components )
    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/forms )
    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/utilities )

    # Look in components folder when determining which classes to include.
    config.assets.css_compressor = Tailwindcss::Compressor.new(files_with_class_names: Rails.root.glob("app/components/**/*.*"))
  end
end
```

```rb
# application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session, prepend: true

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  default_form_builder Forms::Builder

  attr_writer :title

  helper_method :body_class, :title

  def authorize(record, query = nil)
    super([:authorization, record], query)
  end

  def body_class
    "#{params[:controller].gsub('/', '_')}"
  end

  def policy_scope(scope)
    super([:authorization, scope])
  end

  def title
    @title || default_title
  end

  private

  def default_title
    controller_name.singularize.humanize.capitalize
  end
end
```

```rb
# development.rb

require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  config.session_store :cache_store

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded any time
  # it changes. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise exceptions for disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :raise

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Annotate rendered view with file names.
  # config.action_view.annotate_rendered_view_with_filenames = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  # Uncomment if you wish to allow Action Cable access from any origin.
  # config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
end
```

Comment: Is it possible your request to `home` is triggering `protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session`?

Comment: @JakeWorth the anti-CSRF protection should not be triggered for a GET quest. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L289

Comment: And are all requests to that endpoint `GET` requests? Or does removing that guard change behavior? Trying to rule out simple explanations based on the code I see.

Comment: All requests are `GET`. Removing `protect_from_forgery`, or changing the strategy (exception, reset, etc.) all produce the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. Turns out that I had copied the setting `config.session_store :cache_store` in `development.rb` from a different project I had been working on. However, this setting was added as part of the [StimulusReflex](https://github.com/stimulusreflex/stimulus_reflex) setup for that other project.

From the [StimulusReflex docs](https://docs.stimulusreflex.com/hello-world/setup):

> **Cookie-based session storage is not currently supported by StimulusReflex.**
>
> Instead, we enable caching in the development environment so that we can assign our user session data to be managed by the cache store.

The default setting for this option is `cookie_store`. By changing it to `:cache_store` without specifying a cache repo, it implements [ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CacheStore.html) and defaults to storing it in `Rails.cache`, which [uses](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/04/17/rails-built-in-cache-stores.html) the `:file_store` option, which dumps it in `tmp/cache`.

However, further down in `development.rb`, there is some conditional logic that assigns `config.cache_store` to `:null_store` if there is no `caching-dev.txt` file. This implements [ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/NullStore.html), which is "a cache store implementation which doesn't actually store anything."

So because I had not enabled caching with `rails dev:cache` for this project, the session cache was getting toasted with every request.

**LESSON LEARNED: Be very careful when copying config settings from an old project to a new one!**